# no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'list')"

Tags: r

I expected the file to run with no error:

```
overallclaimspaid <- overallclaimspaid %>% rename_at(vars(oldnames), ~ newnames)  
head(overallclaimspaid)
```

Comment: add `as_tibble()`or `as.data.frame()` to your pipe before `rename_at`...

Answer (score 0):

The error `no applicable method for …` means that you're using a function that does not know how to deal with the type of object that you're using it on. In this case, you're using the `rename_at()` function, which needs to be provided with a data frame (or tibble) to work. So your code will work if `overallclaimspaid` is a data frame, but not if it's another type of object.

From the error message, it looks like `overallclaimspaid` is a matrix, rather than a data frame. Depending on the structure of the matrix, you may (as noted in a comment on your question) be able to add `as_tibble()` to your pipeline before `rename_at()`. But before you do that, use `View(overallclaimspaid)` to view the structure of the `overallclaimspaid` object, then use `View(as_tibble(overallclaimspaid))` to see if you're happy with the structure once it has been converted to a tibble.

If that doesn't work as expected, or you need further help, please edit your question to include a *minimal working example* so that we can run the code to explore any issues. You can find out how to create a minimal working example using [the tutorial provided by Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or using the [`reprex` package in R](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html).